# Remember me functionality with laravel vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a LoginComponent in vue js. I want to add remember me in my login form.
I have a remember me checkbox and if checked sending status true else false.

`<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input remember" id="customCheck"  name="example1">`

On controller

`$remember_me = $request->has('remember_me') ? true : false;`

I want my checkbox checked on login page if i select remember me as checked

Comment: your name attribute is called `example1` but you use `remember_me` in the controller.. those should be the same. And I don't understand what's your question here.

Comment: If they're remembered, won't they *not* see the login screen?

Comment: i have added 
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input remember" id="customCheck"  name="example1" v-model="user.rememberme">
and passed true and false on checked.

Comment: No they are showing on Login Screen. I am using  a vue component/page for login form